# Prestashop 1.6 - Attachments from edit product tab in order detail dasboard

Tags: prestashop

I need to add attachment (link to download directly) from product edit tab in order product list. This is not an attachment that customers add.

I edit: [this theme](https://example.com/adminxxxyyy/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/_product_line.tpl) (42 line) after product name, but it's not working.

```
{if isset($product.product_attachments) && $product.attachments->id}
 <a href="{$link->getPageLink('attachment', true,
 NULL,"id_attachment={$attachment.id_attachment}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">attachment</a>
{/if}
```

Attachment file from eit product tab.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpnYw.jpg)

Prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 0):

$product.product_attachments is not defined

$attachment is not defined

$product.attachments is not defined

You can get attachment**s** of product using this:

```
Attachment::getAttachments($id_lang, $id_product);
```